# Module object is not callable in locust 0.13.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, locust, load-generator

when i run `locust -f /desktop/locustfile.py` the following error occurs

```
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/fatima/.local/bin/locust", line 11, in <module>
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: sys.exit(main())
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 525, in main
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,858] fatima/ERROR/stderr: gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_term_handler)
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,859] fatima/ERROR/stderr: TypeError
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,859] fatima/ERROR/stderr: :
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,859] fatima/ERROR/stderr: 'module' object is not callable
[2020-06-18 12:09:27,859] fatima/ERROR/stderr:
```

i am using **python: 3.7**, 
**locust 0.13.0**
and here is the code

```
import random
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, between

products = [
    '0PUK6V6EV0',
    '1YMWWN1N4O',
    '2ZYFJ3GM2N',
    '66VCHSJNUP',
    '6E92ZMYYFZ',
    '9SIQT8TOJO',
    'L9ECAV7KIM',
    'LS4PSXUNUM',
    'OLJCESPC7Z']

def index(l):
    l.client.get("/")

def setCurrency(l):
    currencies = ['EUR', 'USD', 'JPY', 'CAD']
    l.client.post("/setCurrency",
        {'currency_code': random.choice(currencies)})

def browseProduct(l):
    l.client.get("/product/" + random.choice(products))

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        index(self)

    tasks = {index: 1,
        setCurrency: 2,
        browseProduct: 10,
        }

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    wait_time = between(1, 10)
```

i run the locust 0.13.0 documentation [example](https://docs.locust.io/en/0.13.0/quickstart.html) and it also gives me same error. I thought may be its the python version issue so i install python 2.7 and again run locust on it but still same error.

Answer (score 3):

Locust 0.13.0 is fairly old. You might want to try the latest version which is 1.0.3.

But supposing you do want Locust 0.13.0 after all, the error you're getting is because `gevent` has broken its API since the version that locust was developed against -- `gevent.signal` is no longer a method, but a module.

```
(locust2) hyperair@blah:/tmp% pip freeze | grep gevent
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
gevent==20.6.2
geventhttpclient-wheels==1.3.1.dev2
(locust2) hyperair@blah:/tmp% python
Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gevent
>>> gevent.signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'
>>> from gevent import signal
>>> signal
<module 'gevent.signal' from '/home/hyperair/.virtualenvs/locust2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/signal.pyc'>
```

Downgrading gevent to `1.2.2` makes it work:

```
(locust) hyperair@blah:/tmp% pip install gevent==1.2.2
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting gevent==1.2.2
  Using cached gevent-1.2.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.10 in /home/hyperair/.virtualenvs/locust/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent==1.2.2) (0.4.16)
Installing collected packages: gevent
  Attempting uninstall: gevent
    Found existing installation: gevent 20.6.2
    Uninstalling gevent-20.6.2:
      Successfully uninstalled gevent-20.6.2
Successfully installed gevent-1.2.2
(locust) hyperair@blah:/tmp% cd ./locust
(locust) hyperair@blah:/tmp/locust% ls
locustfile.py  locustfile.pyc
(locust) hyperair@blah:/tmp/locust% locust -f locustfile.py
[2020-06-18 17:51:08,898] blah/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089
[2020-06-18 17:51:08,898] blah/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 0.13.0
^C[2020-06-18 17:51:10,144] blah/ERROR/stderr: KeyboardInterrupt
[2020-06-18 17:51:10,144] blah/ERROR/stderr: Thu Jun 18 17:51:10 2020
[2020-06-18 17:51:10,144] blah/ERROR/stderr:
[2020-06-18 17:51:10,145] blah/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 0), bye.
[2020-06-18 17:51:10,145] blah/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
[2020-06-18 17:51:10,145] blah/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
 Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s failures/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregated                                                         0     0(0.00%)                                       0.00    0.00

Percentage of the requests completed within given times
 Name                                                           # reqs    50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it was the gevent version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like maybe you installed locust for both python2 and python3? I'm not sure what the actual error is, but assuming you dont *want* to run python2, I suggest you try:

removing it for python2

```
pip uninstall locustio
```

installing it for python3

```
pip3 install locust
```

(locust package has been renamed from locustio to locust)

There are a few breaking changes in the 1.0 release of locust as well, so you'll need to change from HttpLocust to HttpUser (see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#changelog-1-0 for more details)